# How to add custom config.js in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, ckeditor

I am not able to add custom config file to ckeditor in grails.
Here is my code:

```
function applyEditor() {
    try {

        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
            customConfig : '../ckeditor/custom_config.js',

            toolbarGroups : [ {"name" : "basicstyles",
                "groups" : [ "basicstyles", "cleanup" ]
            }, {
                "name" : "links",
                "groups" : [ "links" ]
            }, {
                "name" : "insert",
                "groups" : [ "insert" ]
            }, {
                "name" : "paragraph",
                "groups" : [ "list", "blocks", "align" ]
            },
            {
                "name" : "styles"
            },
            {
                "name" : 'colors'
            }, {
                "name" : 'editing',
                "groups" : [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ]
            }, ],
            removeButtons : 'Image,Flash,Iframe'
        });
    } catch (e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

Custom_config.js is placed under 
`/target/work/plugins/ckeditor-4.4.1.0/web-app/js/ckeditor/custom_config.js`

Please help me out. 
Thanx in advance.

Comment: which version of Grails are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using in a right way. Check your code again. There must be some other problem. 
Add custom config to your ckeditor:

```
CKEDITOR.config.customConfig = '/your/path/ckeditor_config.js';
```

You can refer this for more details : [LINK](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/config.js-changes-not-reflected)